# h2o: what is the role of hex key argument

Tags: r, h2o

What does the key argument does in h2o? why we need to specify it?

I looked for an answer but couldn't find anything satisfactory. It appears as if I am missing something very obvious. I haven't seen it in R.

```
h2o.assign(data, key)

Arguments
data    An H2OFrame object
key     The hex key to be associated with the H2O parsed data object
```

e.g.

```
df <- h2o.importFile(path = normalizePath("../data/covtype.full.csv"))
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(df, c(0.6,0.2), seed=1234)
valid  <- h2o.assign(splits[[2]], "valid.hex")
```

Comment: The key is what will show up for the command h2o.ls.  It's H2O's name for the object rather than the R object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use h2o.assign it will create copy of given dataset as first argument into the name given as second argument i.e. key.

So if you will write the command as below:

```
valid  <- h2o.assign(df, "hhh.hex")
```

It will take df dataframe and create a new H2O specific dataframe name hhh.hex. So if you will call h2o.ls() below you will see new h2o specific dataframe as below:

```
> h2o.ls()

                           key
 1                     hhh.hex
```

Comment: The "key" in is just a unique identifier that the H2O cluster uses to keep track of H2OFrames.  This can be a different name than the R object that represents the H2OFrame in R.

Comment: Ok.  What is the h2o key in case of df? That's also a h2oframe. Right? Also where it is used?